# Navigation not working on custom button react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hope someone would help me with this problem. I have create my own buttons and when I`m calling them as a component in a screen onPress navigation is not working, only in the Button Component from react native. This is my code:

Custom Button:

```
export const MediumButton = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.mediumButton}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

And this is the code of screen that I`m calling the MediumButton:

```
import { MediumButton } from "../../components/Button/Button";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={global.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Miresevini ne Hajde App</Text>
        <MediumButton
          title="Kycu"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}
        />
        <MediumButton
          title="Regjistrohu"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the onPress prop that you are passing like below

```
export const MediumButton = ({ title,onPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.mediumButton} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer its working, but not inside the Formik cause I`m using Formik library for Validation. This error appears: createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. ... You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in

Comment: That error generally appears when you mix up the default import with named one, can you check that, i dont think that formik does any specific change

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the `onPress` handler to `TouchableOpacity`:

```
export const MediumButton = ({ title, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.mediumButton} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```